# Writing a CSV parser where number of cloumn and position is not defined

Tags: java, csv, generics

Basically i need to write a csv parser that will take consideration of mapping defined by user. AT the same time the sequence of column is not defined and as well as user can have any number of columns but Application will consider only from matched columns from mapping.

I tried to create a map where key will be user cloumn and value will be hibernate entity cloumn.

Next step would be to find out if entry is found and if found out the next step would be to find out the position of column.

```
    try {

        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

        String line = "";
        fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        line=fileReader.readLine();
        String[] headers = line.split(COMMA_DELIMITER);
        int columnCounter=0;
        for(String a : headers){// parsing the header

            String columnName=clientMapping.get(a);//gettting actual column from mapping defined by user

            if(columnName !=null){
                switch(columnName.toUpperCase()){

                case "FNAME":
                    STUDENT_FNAME=columnCounter;// finding the position of column
                    break;

                case "LNAME":
                    STUDENT_LNAME=columnCounter;
                    break;

                case "SEX" :
                    STUDENT_GENDER=columnCounter;
                    break;
                case "ID" :
                    STUDENT_ID=columnCounter;
                    break;
                case "AGE" :
                    STUDENT_AGE=columnCounter;  
                    break;

                 default :
                     System.out.println("default");

                }
            }
            columnCounter++;

        }
        //Read the file line by line starting from the second line
        while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
            //Get all tokens available in line
            String[] tokens = line.split(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            if (tokens.length > 0) {
                //Create a new student object and fill his  data
          Student student = new Student(Long.parseLong( STUDENT_ID == -1 ? null : tokens[STUDENT_ID]),STUDENT_FNAME == -1 ? null: tokens[STUDENT_FNAME], STUDENT_LNAME == -1 ? null : tokens[STUDENT_LNAME], STUDENT_GENDER == -1 ? null:tokens[STUDENT_GENDER],STUDENT_AGE == -1 ? null: Integer.parseInt(tokens[STUDENT_AGE]));
                students.add(student);
            }
        }
```

Its working as fine but this will work only for Student Class as it is not generic.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I need a generic solution where I don't have to code for the particular Class. Like in above example i am finding the student_id , student_lname etc . The above solution is only for student class. What if someone says i need this solution for Employee Class. I hope you got my question .

Comment: Don't tell me in a comment. Edit the question and clarify it, so everybody will understand what you're asking. Delete the comment.

Comment: Seems your question is asking how to use reflection to learn what constructor / setter methods are available. Do a web search for Java reflection to learn about it.